# Grails: how to distinct one transaction from another?

Tags: hibernate, grails, transactions, grails-orm

Executing a line of code and another line, how could I tell whether they are executed within the same hibernate transaction or within different? Having current transaction's unique ID available would be an useful feature while investigating hard bugs.

I tried casting `TransactionStatus` to an implementation `DefaultTransactionStatus` which has method `getTransaction()` but that resulted in three HibernateTransactionObject's with different hashCode... Not helpful.

In the example below I wanted to have expressions like `status1 ne status2` and `status2 eq status3`. But `equals()` returns always `false` for both `TransactionStatus` and `HibernateTransactionObject`:

```
Dog.withTransaction { TransactionStatus status1 ->
    Dog.withNewTransaction { TransactionStatus status2 ->
        Dog.withTransaction { TransactionStatus status3 ->
            print(status1)
            print(status2)
            print(status3)
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionStatus@d42932c / org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager$HibernateTransactionObject@3f02d1d0
org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionStatus@598b083a / org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager$HibernateTransactionObject@dcc3481
org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionStatus@5803214e / org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager$HibernateTransactionObject@36c945c3
```

Grails 2.2.0, Hibernate 3.6

Comment: Follow [AbstractPlatformTransactionManager](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-tx/src/main/java/org/springframework/transaction/support/AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java#L336) where a new DefaultTransactionStatus is created each time. withTransaction and `withNewTransaction` use the default propagation strategy [PROPAGATION_REQUIRED] unless otherwise specified, which results in handling creating a new transaction status every time, therefore transaction status bear not much relevance other than rolling back transactions where necessitated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in a hack-ish way, relying on "connection holder" which is "Transaction-aware proxy for target Connection". I'd be glad to find a cleaner way for sure. For the initial example, this method gives correct UID's: `status1 != status2 && status2 == status3`. Although I'm not sure it is stable, it could be useful for debugging.

```
// groovy code, not java
int getCurrentTransactionUid(TransactionStatus ts) {
  DefaultTransactionStatus dts = ts
  return dts.transaction.connectionHolder.hashCode()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another way, just sending a TransactionDefinition with the name that you want.

```
public void updateStatusSomething(somethingToUpdate, anotherThingToUpdate) {
    def transactionDefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition()
    transactionDefinition.setName("MY TRANSACTION NAME")
    Domain.withTransaction(transactionDefinition) {
        updateSomething(somethingToUpdate)
        updateAnotherThing(anotherThingToUpdate)
    }
}
```

And if you add this to your log4j Config.groovy

```
trace 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTransactionManager'
```

In your logs you are going to see something like this:

> 2015/07/08 11:55:05 [hibernate.GrailsHibernateTransactionManager] Creating new transaction with name [MY TRANSACTION NAME]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT

Hope it helps, it's good advice that you should trace this just in case you actually need it, to debug or to test something.